# How can I calculate the np.gradient combined with another column value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gradient

This is my data frame:

```
    Index        Beacon Average    
    2017-06-10    A18   4.5566
    2017-06-10    B18   5.6694
    2017-06-10    C17   3.7341
    2017-06-15    A18   4.5528
    2017-06-15    B18   5.6663
              ...      ...
    2017-08-16   SB01   3.8360
    2017-08-16   SB02   3.7130
    2017-08-16   SB03   3.5610
    2017-08-16   SB04   3.9790
    2017-08-16   SB05   3.7230
```

I know I can calculate the gradient of the 'Average' column by using the following command:

```
df['gradient'] = np.gradient(df['Average'])
```

But I need the gradient based on the 'Beacon' column. For example, based on the order datetimeIndex it returns the gradients of A18. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

After assigning

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Beacon'])
```

you'll be in a position to obtain the gradients you desire.

EDIT

```
for grp in grouped.groups:
    print(grp)
    print(grouped.get_group(grp))
    print(np.gradient(grouped.get_group(grp).Average))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I tried this but i dont know how to imply the np.gradient function. So if I do 
df = df.groupby(by=['Beacon']).np.gradient(df['Average']) it will give the error:  AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'np'